# How to get params from url Node Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I'm building an application in Node JS and Express that optimizes images, I need the information to request an image to be requested like this:

```
filename.jpg?w=1280&h=720
```

The app will have to The app will have to return an image(`filename.jpg`) with the width (`w`) and the height (`h`)
This already works (I use sharp), but I don't know how to get the image scaling information from the URL

This is the code for now

Router file:

```
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/:image/:size', Controller.getImage)
```

Controller file:

```
export default {
  getImage: [
    async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const { image, size } = req.params

        const path = await generateFile(image, size)

        res.sendFile(path)
      } catch (err) {
        next(err)
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Function file:

```
import sharp from 'sharp'

async function generateFile (image, size) {
  const x = options.split('-')[0]
  const y = options.split('-')[1]

  sharp('./img/' + image)
    .resize(x, y)
    .toFile(./resized/ + img)
}
```

Comment: Look at [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Heiko Theißen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16462950/heiko-thei%C3%9Fen)

Use `req.query`

This is the solution:

```
getImage: [
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { image } = req.params

      const path = await generateFile(image, req.query)

      res.sendFile(path)
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  }
]
```

```
async function generateFile (image, query) {
  const { x, y } = query

  sharp('./img/' + image)
    .resize(x, y)
    .toFile(./resized/ + img)
}
```